# JavaScript moving text animation doesn't work. FULL CODE

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

**JS:** My problem is in running the following JS script, it's supposed to be very easy ,i think, but i can't understand why won't it run. I've just started coding and i'm already stuck in this problem. I want the text to go up (by increasing the *bottom* in CSS) for 5px until it reaches pos=6 ; then *clearInterval* should do its job.

**CSS:** I've put the position of div's to RELATIVE as i've read in some tutorials but didn't put the " container's " position to ABSOLUTE, may it be the problem?

```html
 <html>

        <head>
          <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      height: ;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: ;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    #generale {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #intestazione {
      height: 7%;
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      background-image: url(immagini/sfumatura.png);
      position: static;
    }

    #profilo {
      position: static;
      float: right;
      width: 12%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .testo_rialzato {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      width: auto;
      height: 100%;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    </style>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div id="generale">
            <div id="intestazione">


              
                <div id="profilo"></div>
              


              
                <div class="testo_rialzato sumba">
                  <p>Sp</p>
                </div>
              



              
                <div class="testo_rialzato ap">
                  <p>App</p>
                </div>
              



              
                <div class="testo_rialzato te">
                  <p>Te</p>
                </div>
             
        


              
                <div class="testo_rialzato do">
                  <p>Dom</p>
                </div>
              


              
                <div class="testo_rialzato big">
                  <p style="line-height:70%; margin-top:8px; text-align:center;">Big</p>
                </div>
              
            </div>

            <script>
    var ez = document.querySelectorAll(".sumba , .ap , .te , .do, .big");
        ez.onmouseover = alza();
    var intervallo = setInterval(alza, 100);

    function alza() {

      var pos = 0;
      if (pos = 6) {
        clearInterval(intervallo);
      } else {
        ez.style.bottom = pos + "px";
      }
    }
    </script>
          </div>
        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet so it reproduces your problem. You need to put all your JS code in there.

Comment: This is something you should not do via JS at all any more these days - CSS Transitions/CSS Animations are the way to go. Performance is usually way better.

Comment: `if (pos = 6)` - that is an _assignment_, not a _comparison_.

Comment: sorry guys im quite confused as i can't edit properly the code, in two hours i will fix it. Thank you for the help u gave me.

Comment: why onmousemove

Comment: Boo Berr'ita It's *onmouseover* not onmousemove

Comment: soory yep but what it's role here , it's usless knowing that the stinterval will trigger automaticly

Comment: CBroe I think u're right, CSS animations are better performant and even more simple to apply.

Comment: Boo Berr'ita U're right, i edited it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is , why declaring you are using event on an array of dome node (result of querySelectorAll will return array of domenodes ) so in order to attach mouseover and also apply some style you have to loop around those nodes .

Seconde thing while declaring set interval, its usless to use mousemovehere ?

Also the condition if is wrong you're using assignment , so you have to use == or === in order to make comaparison .

See below snippet :

```js
var ez = document.querySelectorAll(".sumba , .ap , .te , .do, .big");
var pos = 0;


var intervallo = setInterval(alza, 100);

ez.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("mouseover", alza);
})


function alza() {
   
  if (pos == 25) {
    clearInterval(intervallo);
  } else {
    ez.forEach(function(el){
      el.style.bottom = pos + "px";
    });
    pos++;
  }
}
```

```css
.sumba, .ap {
  position:absolute;
}

.ap {
  color:red;
  left:40px
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<div class="sumba">Text</div>

<div class="ap">Text 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>
<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>
</p> 

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate">ggg</div>
</div>

<script>
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```